# How to detect level audio level of current segment of mp3 playing using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

If i am palying a sound using the AVAudioPlayer in the AVFoundation framework (I can already do this), is there any way to detect the current level of the audio playing, like a VU meter that is listening to the mp3 playing.

I don't want to detect the audio of the mic, just the file playing.

I want to animate a mouth to prerecorded audio that will be played, and don't want to program a whole load of animations (100's and 100's).

In a way the mouth is responding like a VU meter.

I can do all the animation I just need to know how to detect the level.

Anyone done this or know how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [aurioTouch sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/aurioTouch/index.html) from Apple shows how to visualize audio input (time-domain, spectral).

As Apple's sample is pretty complex, you might want to start with this tutorial, which shows how to setup the RemoteIO audio unit: [Using RemoteIO audio unit](http://atastypixel.com/blog/2008/11/04/using-remoteio-audio-unit/)